# Cannot get utop and merlin to work with Core and Base

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml, opam, ocaml-core, merlin

The packages are installed correctly.

```
opam install core                                    
[NOTE] Package core is already installed (current version is v0.14.1)

opam install base
[NOTE] Package base is already installed (current version is v0.14.1).
```

My .ocamlinit file has

```
(* ## added by OPAM user-setup for ocamltop / base ## 3ec62baf6f9c219ae06d9814069da862 ## you can edit, but keep this line *)
(* ## end of OPAM user-setup addition for ocamltop / base ## keep this line *)

#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
```

The really strange thing is - when I startup ocaml's top level using the `ocaml` command
it loads everything up correctly and commands like `open Core;;` `open Base;;` work. But they don't work with utop. I get `Error: Unbound module Core`. Similarly `merlin` in VS-code gives me red-squiggly lines if I write `open Core`.

Can someone help me understand what's happening? I can give you more details if they are helpful. I've already looked at all the similar questions that have been asked and none have helped me solve this.

Edit: If it helps, this is the result of `opam switch`

```
❯ opam switch

#   switch   compiler                    description
->  4.12.0   ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0  4.12.0
    default  ocaml-base-compiler.4.12.0  default
```

Comment: Do you have only one opam switch or multiple ones?

Comment: @Lhooq Edited body to answer your question

Comment: So you have two switches. Can you show the important lines of `opam list`? (I tested on my switch and I have no problem with utop and Base)

Comment: `opam list` has everything `async`, `core` `base`, `ocamlfind`, `ocamlbuild`, `dune`, a bunch of ppx related libs etc.

Comment: Before doing `open Base;;` you wrote `#require "base";;`, right?

Comment: I'm not required to do that in a .ml file right? `No such package: base` when I do it on `utop`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234497/discussion-between-lhooq-and-aditya-bhagwat).

Comment: Side-comment: if you are requiring `#camlp4o`, you are following an out-of-date tutorial.

Comment: What should it be instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utop` was not installed with `opam` but with `brew` so it couldn't find the libraries.

Remember to always clean all OCaml related things before installing everything with `opam` or it may break things.